# Unable to Publish to Web / Public

Tags: powerbi

I am unable to publish to web / public.

After checking my settings under the Admin Portal | Tenant Settings | Publish to Web, I have all the options open:

[image: Publish screenshot]

I checked this [post](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Unable-to-Publish-to-Web/td-p/300828) and they state here that it has something to do with the version of Power BI released in November 2020.

I downloaded the latest Power BI Desktop and installed it, then published my report again - which still did not resolve my problem.

Any idea why this option is not available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a while, I stumbled upon this [solution](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/The-quot-Publish-to-web-quot-button-is-not-shown/m-p/18364#:%7E:text=You%20need%20to%20go%20to,Hope%20it%20works%20for%20you.).

When I started developing my report, I copied the PBIX file (so that I do not have to reinvent the wheel) and plugged this PBIX file into another DB.

What I forgot is, that I needed to remove the row-level security I added for this report under `Modeling`.

I then just removed all the security there, saved and published the report again.

After this, Publish to Web became available for this report.